# Why &a is illegal l-value and why it is used in scanf() function then

Tags: c

I'm studying pointers in C, and I'm finding some topics really confusing.
I searched Google and this particular site too but could not understand them.

I have questions regarding the forms variable take:

***1)***  what is the difference between a=2 and &a=2 ?
***2)***  why `&a` used as a l-value is illegal?

As far as I understand, `&a=2;` is illegal and &a is a illegal l-value because &a contains memory address not the memory contents.
And since memory address is in the form of integer therefore we can't assign value into the integer.

***3)*** what happens in `scanf()` function then?

I mean if we take an example like `scanf("%d",&a);`. why is `&a` used here,  why not `*(&a)`.  Why does compiler not show any kind of error?

Please please help and explain  :)

Comment: This is a question about C fundamentals -- has nothing to do with Objective-C.  `&` means "address of", and is inherently an R-value, not an L-value.  An L-value can be an assignment target, an R-value cannot be.  But one can dereference (with `*`) an R-value (if it's a pointer) to make it an L-value.  This is effectively what `scanf` does.

Comment: (And if you are asking questions at this level you do not understand C well enough to be using Objective-C.)

Comment: Did you read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) ? You really should read it before asking your question....

Comment: @HotLicks +1 for _some_ of the points you make in your first comment.

Comment: ***[C pointers tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html)***, ***[Link to scanf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)***, link to explain ***[L-value, R-value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx)***.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to `&a`, because `&a` denotes the **address** where the variable `a` is stored, and that address is determined once and for all at program start and it can't be changed.

When using `scanf`, you want that one or more variables be modified by the `scanf` function. Therefore you must pass the **address** of the variables to be modified to `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented, understanding ***[scanf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)*** would benefit you.  This link contains some sample code, and good description of use.

And ***[This may help understand what L-value and R-value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx)*** are.

***Your question:***
The address of `a`, i.e. `&a` is assigned at the time `a` is created at runtime.

By attempting the statement `&a = 2;`, you are trying to re-assign the place where `a` resides, or the address.  For example:
Say the address of `a` is 0x0000ABCD
Then your statement would be attempting to assert that

```
0x0000ABCD. = 2;// an illegal assignment
```

This cannot be true, At compile time, the compiler warning is simply notifying you of that mistake.  Re-assignment of an address *in this manner* is not allowed.

***Note***, you *can* use the address of a variable to set a pointer to point to a specific location:

```
int a, *pB;

pB = &a;//now pB points to the location of a
```

Which, to the runtime engine, could look something like:

```
pB = 0x0000ABCD; //a legal assignment
```

Comment: what if i assign it at the start like int &a=2;.

Comment: There had to be a step where `a` was created before that step:  e.g. `int a;`

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your thinking that &a=2 is illegal, as it is trying to store an integer value into an integer. For example, it might equate to 0x0fb8b815 = 2, or 4 = 7, and the compiler won't like that. After all, what would that even mean?

As for scanf(), it takes two arguments. The first describes the type of data you're looking for; "%d" is looking for an integer. The Second argument is where you want the data to be stored.

So:

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

You're giving the memory address of a to scanf, and saying that you want an integer. This works out, because we've declared `a` as type `int`. The &a is *dereferenced*, and turned into a number representing the location in memory that a resides in.  Scanf takes user input, and attempts to put that input into the memory location given as the second argument. You *could* call scanf like this: `scanf("%s", 0x8484af00);`.  You'd be giving it a specific memory location, as an integer literal, for it to store the data. This is a very bad idea, unless you somehow know exactly what that memory location is being used for! the '%s' option says you want a string, so it could be quite lengthy, and an arbitrary memory location like that will have a good chance of upsetting the operating system. A trick like that might try overwriting ram being used by another program, or even by the operating system itself, so it will probably cause a segfault and crash. Always know where you're putting things.

Comment: very good explaination  i must say u have a good understanding about pointers thats really a good thing.As far as what i understand by now is that &a used as an l-value in the expression and &a used in scanf() function is two different thing.Where the formal one is the r-value and can't be used as l-value and in the later one &a is same like a normal variable(a=2 for example) .what scanf() function do is that it takes the address of a (which is written as &a) dereference it and then store that value in the memory. Am i right?

Comment: @SîddhärthSïngh - No,  ***[This may help understand what I-value and R-value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx)*** are